# How to use Entity Framework Core with SQL Server in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, sql-server, xamarin, xamarin.forms, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to use Entity Framework Core with SQL Server (not SQLite) in a Xamarin forms app but I just can't figure it out! All tutorials explain how to use EF Core with sqlite! Are there any clear documentation or tutorials?

Comment: it is a horrible, terrible, very bad idea to connect a mobile app directly to your database server.  Please reconsider your architecture

Comment: @Jason okay so i have two questions, when ever i delete the app from my android device and re deploy it i lose all the data! so how can i seed the sqlite db? and how can i get to the db file and open it in sqlite??

Comment: You can still store your data on a remote server.  You just don't connect DIRECTLY to your database.  Use a services layer to isolate your db from your client.

Comment: @Jason Thanks alot!

Answer (score 4):

About connect to a Remote DataBase in Xamarin.Forms, I find one article that you can take a look:

https://xamarinhelp.com/connecting-remote-database-xamarin-forms/

You may be wondering why you couldn’t just connect directly to a database from your mobile app? The main reasons are:

**Security**

You don’t want your mobile client apps to have a database connection string with a username and password in it. It opens your database up to anyone. You can create a user with read only permissions and only allow access to certain tables, but they could still see all data in these tables. On an API, you can implement additional security checks and have authentication based on OAuth or an existing user management system.

**Performance**

Database connections weren’t designed to go over high latency connections. It is likely your database connection would keep dropping, forcing you to reconnect every time.

**Control**

With an API you can control the flow of data to and from your database. You can implement rate limiting, and monitoring of all of your requests. If you need to change business logic, or even what database or resources are used via each API request, you can do this on the server, without having to redeploy a mobile app.

**Resources**

With an API, you reduce the need for server resources. While you may have to setup another server to handle an API, the REST API is designed to be stateless and efficient. Scaling to many users in the future is easier with an API.